# urdf in rviz is too deep

Tags: collision, avoidance, hector, frames, base-link

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I setup my robot system and its working good.

I am using hector mapping with urdf and a laserscanner and I am getting the following result:
[image: image description]
I dont know why exactly the robot is kind of swimming in the world, here is my tf tree:

[image: image description]

Another Question is now, how can I make the Robot move autonomously and how can I integrate a path planner?
What is a common used module to make the robot move and avoid obstacles and crashes?

thanks in advance, felix

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208220/urdf-in-rviz-is-too-deep/) by [felixwatzlawik](https://answers.ros.org/users/22115/felixwatzlawik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2015-04-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-04-30**:
For your second question, you'll want to check out the [navigation stack](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation). It has packages that include local and global path planning, and it is the most common way to get started with autonomous navigation in ROS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I dont know why exactly the robot is kind of swimming in the world [..]

A likely reason is because you have placed the origin of your urdf (typically called `base_link`) in the centre of the yellow (?) cube. The origin of a cube in URDF is not at one of its corners, but in its centre.

If you place you `base_link` (or whatever the first link of your robot is called) at ground level, your robot should no longer be 'swimming'.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0